# C# WPF datagrid: ItemsSource

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, wpftoolkit, itemssource

I want to know how you can modify properties of columns of a WPF toolkit datagrid once the ItemsSource has been set (it is set in XAML)? For example I want to make a specific column have the property IsReadOnly equal to true.

So basically there are two things I want to know:

> -How can I get access to a specific column once the ItemsSource has been
>   set?
>
> -How can I change the properties of a specific column once the ItemsSource
>   has been set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to both questions is:

- By looping through your datagrid
- Access column by it's index

Comment: That simple! :S I am new to C# and WPF. I was searching for something way more complicated. Thank you.